# Dissmissing the keyboard when UITextField and UITextview displayed inside of UIWindow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uiwindow

I've added my `UITextField` and `UITextView` inside a `UIWindow` I can not able to type inside in both of them. Both are not letting me allow to type in those fields. And, can't able to dismiss it when *return* pressed in keyboard.

```
-(void)showAlert 
{
alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
alertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 115, 300, 230)];
alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert; // puts it above the status bar
alertView.center = CGPointMake(alertWindow.frame.size.width/2, alertWindow.frame.size.height/2);
alertView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
alertView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
alertView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];

UITextField *txt = ....
....
....
txt.delegate = self;
...
...
[alertView addSubview:txt];

UITextView *txtview = ...
....
....
txtview.delegate = self;
...
[alertView addSubview:txtview];

[alertWindow addSubview:alertView];
[alertWindow addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:alertView duration:1.0 option:curveValues[0]];
[alertWindow setHidden:NO];
}
```

I've declared both of the delegate methods also. I placed a breakpoint there and checked also, even that method not yet called.

**Update -**

`textFieldShouldReturn` delegate method

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [reserveView resignFirstResponder];
    [reserveWindow resignFirstResponder];
    [self.reserveWindow endEditing:YES];
    [reserveView endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, that method has not been called because of `UIWindow` So, i changed my `UIWindow` to `UIView` And, i fixed this issue by using `UIView+Animation.h` from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes) It provides the animation what i required exactly.

```
- (void) addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option;
- (void) removeWithZoomOutAnimation:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option;
```

Thanks to Google! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should try this for dismiss the keyboard from the UIWindow

```
[self.window endEditing:YES];
```

[Source](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/100156-dismiss-keyboard-from-a-uiwindow.html)

Comment: Can you please see my updated code. `textFieldShouldReturn` not even called yet. Check with breakpoint also :(

Comment: Thanks! I found the issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard will never dismiss on its own (even if you hit return!). You'll notice that in your delegate methods, you will receive events whenever you press return/done/etc.

A simple way to make the keyboard dismiss *every time someone hits the return key* is to implement the `- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView` method.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: In your post you edited to say that you've declared both of the delegate methods... there are more than two so could you clarify what methods you've implemented? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextViewDelegate

Comment: Thanks! I found the issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
  tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
  [self.window addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
  //[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
  [tapGesture release];
}
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
[txt resignFirstResponder];
[textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

That's the delegate method of textfield:-

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

  {

  ```
  [txtview resignFirstResponder];
  ```

  return NO;

  }

Comment: Thanks! I found the issue and fixed it.